# ArrayList of Strings to one single string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an array list of strings (each individual element in the array list is just a word with no white space) and I want to take each element and append each next word to the end of a string.

So say the array list has

```
    element 0 = "hello"
    element 1 = "world,"
    element 2 = "how"
    element 3 = "are"
    element 4 = "you?"
```

I want to make a string called sentence that contains "hello world, how are you?"

Comment: Hi, consider accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 33):

As of Java 8, this has been added to the standard Java API:

**`String.join()` methods:**

```
String joined = String.join("/", "2014", "10", "28" ); // "2014/10/28"

List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
joined = String.join(";", list); // "foo;bar;baz"
```

**`StringJoiner` is also added:**

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
joiner.add("foo");
joiner.add("bar");
joiner.add("baz");
String joined = joiner.toString(); // "foo,bar,baz"
```

Plus, it's nullsafe, which I appreciate.  By this, I mean if `StringJoiner` encounters a `null` in a `List`, it won't throw a NPE:

```
@Test
public void showNullInStringJoiner() {
    StringJoiner joinedErrors = new StringJoiner("|");
    List<String> errorList = Arrays.asList("asdf", "bdfs", null, "das");
    for (String desc : errorList) {
        joinedErrors.add(desc);
    }

    assertEquals("asdf|bdfs|null|das", joinedErrors.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Like suggested in the comments you can do it using `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder listString = new StringBuilder();

for (String s : list)
     listString.append(s).append(" ");
```

or without the explicit loop:

```
list.forEach(s -> listString.append(s).append(" "));
```

or even more elegant with Java 8 capabilities:

```
String listString = String.join(" ", list);
```

Comment: this way is the fastest of the mentioned here, btw

Answer (score 13):

Use StringUtils to solve this.

e.g. Apache Commons Lang offers the join method.

```
StringUtils.join(myList,","))
```

It will iterate through your array or list of strings and will join them, using the 2nd parameter as seperator. Just remember - there is always a library for everything to make things easy.

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8**

```
final String concatString= List.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Why the hyphen?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a standard for loop should work:

```
String toPrint = "";
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
  toPrint += list.get(i)+" ";
}
System.out.println(toPrint);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just add spaces between the words.

Comment: Thanks! Edited to include that.

Comment: Also add the "," between "world, how"... just kidding.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked like a charm. now i just have to add the space in there.

Comment: If he's a beginner, he may as well use something basic.

Comment: i am a beginner but id love to learn about it and maybe i can learn enough to use it but i got it working which is what i need. thanks!

Comment: This does not scale, strings in Java cannot be changed (immutable) so looping around like this might look like it's extending a single string but is actually creating lots of temporary ones. Better to use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
String ret = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    ret += array.get(i) + " ";
}
```

But if your array is long, performance of string concat is poor. You should use StringBuilder class.

Comment: thanks for responding. it is assumed that my string is under a certain manageable length. its just for a simple class; nothing too complicated ha

Answer (score -1):

this is simple method

String value = TextUtils.join(" ", sample);

sample is arraylist

Comment: This does not belong to the standard APIs.